# How to change the size of the sys_call_table in linux kernel 2.4?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system, gnu-assembler

The file linux/arch/i386/kernel/entry.S contains the list of system calls:

```
ENTRY(sys_call_table)
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_ni_syscall)   /* 0  -  old "setup()" system call*/
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_exit)
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_fork)
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_read)
          .
          .
          .
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_start_monitor)    /* 243 */   
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_stop_monitor) /* 244 */ 
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_get_all_events_number)    /* 245 */
    .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_get_events)   /* 246 */
      .rept NR_syscalls-(.-sys_call_table)/4
          .long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_ni_syscall)
    .endr
```

I've added 243-246. I want to make sure that the size of the table grows accordingly. I suspect lines 247-248 have to do with it but I'm not sure.  I know in older versions of linux I'd have needed to increase a counter but I can't find it here.

So what do lines 247-248 do? Does the table size grow automatically or do I need to change something?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
.rept NR_syscalls-(.-sys_call_table)/4
.long SYMBOL_NAME(sys_ni_syscall)
.endr
```

Looks like it pads out the `sys_call_table` to `NR_syscalls` longs.  I think `NR_syscalls` might be what you need to adjust.

Comment: Do you know how? I don't see a counter or anything like that that I'd need to change.